# What's a more formal term for "van man"?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, formality

Not sure about other countries, but in England we have the term "van man" or "man with a van", to describe someone (typically a man as you might imagine,) who is self-employed, and delivers goods in their van to wherever they are needed.

I don't actually know if we have a formal term for this person, as I want to describe it in a cover letter for a job application. It seems a bit colloquial to include. Any suggestions?

Comment: Independent delivery service?

Comment: Independent courier?

Comment: Both good suggestions. I like delivery service.

Comment: How formal?  “Materials Transportation Expert”

Comment: @DanBron "Men with vans" don't restrict themselves to delivery work, the often take on other work like light removals.

Comment: Related: [White van man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_van_man). Job sites usually use the term "delivery driver" and they might include the term "independent contractor".